# Shell Script to hard code a word and read log file

Tags: shell

I have recently started learning shell scripting and I am trying to create one shell script which would read a recent statement from log file and would add a pre-defined word "EDHDEV:ERROR " in the result file along with the error description.I have tried from my end.Below is my snippet.

```
tail -f|egrep -wi 'exception|critical' /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera- scm-server.log|echo "EDHDEV:ERROR" >>subash.txt
```

Below is the error line from log

```
2018-03-29 05:30:57,334 ERROR WebServerImpl:com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.TsqueryAutoCompleter: Error getting predicates
```

So the text file will be appended in below format

```
<timestamp> EDHDEV:Error:<Error description>
```

It should be as below

```
2018-03-29 05:30:57 edhdev:ERROR:WebServerImpl:com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.TsqueryAutoCompleter: Error getting predicates.
```

Any suggestion on the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `echo` doesn't read from stdin, so it never sees the line from the logfile. You could replace your echo command by `xargs -L 1 echo EDHDEV:Error:`. The `-L 1` ensures that only one input line is placed as trailing argument in the subsequent command.